# Constructing VTEC values out of UNAVCO data

Tags: gps, satellite

I'm going through the high-frequency UNAVCO RINEX 2.11 files to create atmospheric maps of the total electron content at a particular timestamp over a particular lat/lon range.

I'm looking for resources that tell me how to convert the RINEX observations into slant-TEC or vertical-TEC values but I can't find one (all the links on UNAVCO's webpages return a 404 error.)

Is there a straightforward resource that tells me exactly how to perform this conversion? I feel like it can't be that hard but I can't find the metadata for the RINEX files either so I don't know what values to put in for, say, f1 and f2 if I try to apply the formula myself.